Filtering data within date range based on record data is always timing out using EF Core. Am I doing something that causes such poor performance?
I have a test which many records over time. I am using Postgresql to store these tests and records and I want to be able to search for tests that have records that fall within a certain time range.
A test has many records, and each record has a collectionTime value which is stored as a DateTime. When I search for all tests, I use a query as follows using EF Core and Linq:
var tests = Table.Include(t => t.RecordData)
                 .AsSplitQuery().AsNoTracking()
                 .Select(r => new Test 
                              { 
                                  Id = r.Id,
                                  // ...additional test info here...
                                  FirstReported = r.RecordData.OrderBy(rd => rd.CollectionDate).FirstOrDefault().CollectionDate,
                                  LastReported = r.RecordData.OrderByDescending(rd => rd.CollectionDate).FirstOrDefault().CollectionDate,
                                  NumberOfRecords = r.RecordData.Count,
                              });

At this point, I begin performing different filtering and sorting. This modifies the resultant query depending on what filters the user applies. If the users simply fetches all the records, at which point they are paginated and returned with no filtering, there is no problem with the query. However, when I add my logic to check if a certain time period was provided, my query consistently times out.
if (providedStartDate is not null)
{
    var startDateUTC = providedStartDate.ToUniversalTime().Date;
    tests = tests.Where(x => x.NumberOfRecords > 0 && x.LastReported >= startDateUTC);
}

I have a nearly identical condition for checking if the FirstReported collection time is after the providedEndDate, as filtering out both sides like that logically results in the tests that I desire.
After paginating the results, I send them to a list:
return await tests.ToListAsync(token);

I similarly want to count the number of records for pagination purposes, and CountAsync also stalls out when filtering for tests within the date range.
Any suggestions or immediate concerns with the query and logic on why this query performs so poorly/times out? I figure this is something that is fairly common, but I can't seem to find any specific posts that address optimizing searches like this. Thanks.
The raw SQL that is generated for the StartDate is as follows when excluding the additional info. Note I have a query filter to only fetch active records and tests, but ignoring query filters also did not affect performance in any notable way:
SELECT 
    t."Id", 
    (SELECT t2."CollectionDate"
     FROM public."RecordData" AS t2
     WHERE t2."IsActive" = TRUE AND t."Id" = t2."TestId"
     ORDER BY t2."CollectionDate"
     LIMIT 1) AS "FirstReported", 
    (SELECT t3."CollectionDate"
     FROM public."RecordData" AS t3
     WHERE t3."IsActive" = TRUE AND t."Id" = t3."TestId"
     ORDER BY t3."CollectionDate" DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS "LastReported", 
    (SELECT count(*)::int
     FROM public."RecordData" AS t4
     WHERE t4."IsActive" = TRUE AND t."Id" = t4."TestId") AS "NumberOfRecords"
FROM 
    public."Tests" AS t
WHERE 
    t."IsActive" = TRUE 
    AND (SELECT count(*)::int
         FROM public."RecordData" AS t0
         WHERE t0."IsActive" = TRUE AND t."Id" = t0."TestId") > 0 
    AND (SELECT t1."CollectionDate"
         FROM public."RecordData" AS t1
         WHERE t1."IsActive" = TRUE AND t."Id" = t1."TestId"
         ORDER BY t1."CollectionDate" DESC
         LIMIT 1) >= @__startDateUTC_0
LIMIT @__p_2 OFFSET @__p_1


Can you show, which SQL is generated? Does query performs bad even when you comment out ...additional test info here... code section?

The additional info isn't bogging it down. I removed it to the same result. I will get the generated SQL and add it to my question.

I don't like trimmed query, please show everything. Also whole LINQ query, I do not see why EF generates other subqueries.

I'm not sure what you mean. I believe that is everything?

First SELECT is missing, query starts from subquery expression.

Ah, I see what you mean. It was the formatting, the SELECT was on the same line with the 3 backticks. My apologies

Any suggestions or immediate concerns -- Please be more specific. See Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?.

Looks like it is bad EF Core LINQ translation, try the following. Everything should measured but EF may create better query.
var tableQuery = Table.AsQueryable();

if (providedStartDate is not null)
{
    var startDateUTC = providedStartDate.ToUniversalTime().Date;
    tableQuery = tableQuery.Where(x => x.RecordData.Any(r => r.CollectionDate >= startDateUTC));
}

var tests = 
    from t in tableQuery
    from first in t.RecordData
        .OrderBy(rd => rd.CollectionDate)
        .Take(1).DefautIfEmpty()
    from last in t.RecordData
        .OrderByDescending(rd => rd.CollectionDate)
        .Take(1).DefautIfEmpty()
    select new Test
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        // ...additional test info here...
        FirstReported = first.CollectionDate,
        LastReported = last.CollectionDate,
        NumberOfRecords = t.RecordData.Count(),
    };

Or using grouping query
var tableQuery = Table.AsQueryable();

if (providedStartDate is not null)
{
    var startDateUTC = providedStartDate.ToUniversalTime().Date;
    tableQuery = tableQuery.Where(x => x.RecordData.Any(r => r.CollectionDate >= startDateUTC));
}

var minMaxQuery = 
  from t in tableQuery
  from rd in t.RecordData
  group rd by new { r.Id } into g
  select new 
  {
      FirstReported = g.Min(x => CollectionDate)
      LastReported  = g.Max(x => CollectionDate),
      Count = g.Count()
  }

var tests = 
    from t in tableQuery
    from mm in minMaxQuery
        .Where(mm => mm.Id == t.Id)
    select new Test
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        // ...additional test info here...
        FirstReported = mm.FirstReported,
        LastReported = mm.LastReported,
        NumberOfRecords = mm.Count,
    };
``


Hmm, maybe I am doing something wrong, but I have to replace r with t in order to compile. Once I do that, I have the same problem with a timeout. I am still leaving the additional test information out. Is this perhaps a syntax problem with r and t and I'm referencing the wrong table/entities?

Try comment one by one filter criteria and projection to find problematic one, also limit returned recordset. If there is million of rows it will fail.

When projecting with .Select() you do not need .Include() nor .AsSplitQuery(). Performance wise, getting a minimum and maximum value will be impacted greatly by indexing on those dates. A general tip when writing complex queries is to capture the SQL and then run it to get an execution plan and tooling to give indexing suggestions. You can simplify the query a bit, such as:
var tests = Table.AsNoTracking()
    .Select(r => new Test 
    { 
        Id = r.Id,
        // ...additional test info here...
        FirstReported = r.RecordData.Min(rd => rd.CollectionDate),
        LastReported = r.RecordData.Max(rd => rd.CollectionDate),
        NumberOfRecords = r.RecordData.Count,
    });

Depending on the size of the outer table you will likely want to consider an Ordering and Pagination. This will be a potentially expensive query, especially if the RecordData count can get fairly large per outer record.
In these cases I recommend pre-loading only deterministic details about the rows when reading lists. What I mean by this is pre-loading only columns that users would be making decisions on, and for more informational detail which a user might want to inspect, conduct these on an as-requested basis via an asynchronous call.
For example, if I list a bunch of search results and I want to offer a quick view of the first & last related record and record count, my search results do not try and eager load these expensive stats but my view renders a hyper link such as "fetch record stats..." with the OuterTableId which will make an Ajax call (fetch) to the server to get the Min/Max/Count for that single OuterTableId row, which then comes back and JS replaces the "fetch stats" hyperlinks with the dates, counts, etc. for that single row. This defers the "expensive" part of the query to an on-demand call when the information isn't absolutely needed up front. This allows the most useful info to load as quickly as possible while still giving additional detail, (which loads nice and responsively in itself) rather than bogging down every query that bit more.
